# Can I console.debug() and make Chrome Dev-tools breakpoint there?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Can I manually set breakpoints from my code(like by writing console.debug at that point).

Debugging problems with cache, it's important to breakpoint there the first time I load it. If I have to add a breakpoint then reload, I can't test caching(problems with functions not defined on first-load, but working subsequently).

Comment: I think you should just be able to write `debugger` in your code, and Chrome should pause execution there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints?hl=en). Just write `debugger` in your code, and Chrome will pause execution there.

> Manual breakpoints are individual breakpoints that you set on a specific line of code. You can set these via the Chrome DevTools GUI, or by inserting the debugger keyword in your code.

Comment: Also documented [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#setting-breakpoints-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can override `console.debug` and set `debugger` there, so we can change it to below

```
var debugCopy = console.debug.bind(console)
console.debug = function(){
  debugger;
  return debugCopy.apply(console,arguments)
}
```